# Keep running into name not defined on Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

FYI, I am EXTREMELY new to Python and coding in general, I downloaded it a couple days ago and practice an hour or so a day with a tutorial book I purchased on my Kindle.

Now to the problem, I am trying this exercise where I get input from the user and then fill it into a story that I have created. Like a mad lib type thing. Here is the code and below it is the error I get.

```
print('It was a (adjective) October day. The infamous (noun) was (verb) South to escape the Winter.')

def get_adjective():
    """getting the adjective"""
    adj=input('Please provide an adjective:')
    return adj

def get_noun():
    """getting the noun"""
    noun=input('Please provide a noun:')
    return noun

def get_verb():
    """getting the verb"""
    verb=input('Please provide a verb:')
    return verb

get_adjective()
get_noun()
get_verb()

def putting_together(adj,noun,verb):
    """executing story"""
    print('It was a {} October day. The infamous {} was {} South to escape the Winter.'.format(adj,noun,verb))

putting_together(adj,noun,verb)
```

Some of you may already know what is wrong, either way here is the message I get in return when I run it

```
It was a (adjective) October day. The infamous (noun) was (verb) South to escape the Winter.

Please provide an adjective:cold
Please provide a noun:John
Please provide a verb:riding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python36-32/practice.py", line 24, in <module>
    putting_together(adj,noun,verb)
NameError: name 'adj' is not defined
```

So that's it. Any help is appreciated. I will say though, I am new and am not completely familiar with the language. Dumbing things down would be helpful. Thanks yall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the values you are getting from your frunctions `get_adjective()`, `get_noun()`, and `get_verb()`. You could solve it by:

```
putting_together(get_adjective(), get_noun(), get_verb())
```

or you can assign each value to a variable as @bernie has said in his answer:

```
adjective = get_adjective()
noun = get_noun()
verb = get_verb()

putting_together(adjective, noun, verb)
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and it asked me all of my questions (Please provide...) twice, and the answers I entered the second time worked. Strange.

Comment: I got it! Thank you! On to the next exercise

Answer (score 1):

You functions are returning things, use them:

```
adj = get_adjective()
noun = get_noun()
verb = get_verb()
```

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't work. Where would I enter this?